# Redmine 1.4 Repository Creation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

When I try to create a Mercurial Repository for a Project in Redmine 1.4 I am getting the following error: It used to work perfectly fine with Redmine 1.3

```
Rendering /var/redmine/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)


Processing RepositoriesController#create (for 117.201.161.229 at 2012-04-19 00:58:17) [POST]
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"repositories", "commit"=>"Create", "repository_scm"=>"Git", "authenticity_token"=>"D9c30kq2pf/mhM3iGcCvRNykEFamKuFddJXEs+xmSEo=", "action"=>"create", "repository"=>{"url"=>"/home/nettantra_base/domains/hg.nettantra.com/repos/nt-test", "checkout_display_command"=>"0", "path_encoding"=>"", "identifier"=>"", "checkout_description"=>"The data contained in this repository can be downloaded to your computer using one of several clients.\r\nPlease see the documentation of your version control software client for more information.\r\n\r\nPlease select the desired protocol below to get the URL.\r\n", "checkout_overwrite"=>"0", "is_default"=>"1", "checkout_protocols"=>{"-1"=>{"protocol"=>"empty"}, "0"=>{"fixed_url"=>"", "access"=>"permission", "command"=>"git clone", "protocol"=>"Git", "is_default"=>"1"}}, "extra_report_last_commit"=>"0"}, "project_id"=>"test-project"}

NoMethodError (undefined method `project=' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/repositories_controller.rb:49:in `create'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.11) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.11) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99

Rendering /var/redmine/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're running the `redmine_checkout` plugin together with Redmine 1.4, and the latest released version (0.5) of `redmine_checkout` isn't ready for Redmine 1.4.

However there are patches, especially from user [tonybarbieri](https://github.com/tonybarbieri/redmine_checkout), on Github. I merged them and added another fix for running it with Ruby 1.9.3, you can find the result also on [Github](https://github.com/rkallensee/redmine_checkout).

So the solution is to update your `redmine_checkout` plugin version to the latest version on Git master (e.g. by cloning my Github repository):

```
cd vendor/plugins
rm -R redmine_checkout
git clone git://github.com/rkallensee/redmine_checkout.git redmine_checkout
```

Don't forget to run the plugin migrations from the Redmine installation directory:

```
rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production
```

Probably you have to run

```
bundle install --without development test
```

from the Redmine installation directory again (at least I had to - otherwise the `rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production` command failed - even if `bundle install` didn't install any new gems).

Restart your Redmine installation and you should be fine!

Comment: Note: my Github master now contains more changes for Redmine 2.x, who break support for Redmine 1.4.x. So you should checkout the last revision with the 1.4.x changes after cloning if you're using Redmine 1.4.x: just do a `git checkout b86bff1`